# ANOVA, Linear Models, or something else?

Tags: anova, linear-model, environmental-data

I'm a rookie in statistics, but just wrapped up a semester of R analysis for natural resources. I'm working on my grad capstone and hoping I might be able to get some help generating ideas for worthwhile analysis to answer the following questions:

****Changes in Run Timing****
I don't have any effect for this question, but just wanting to show how the timing of the fish run has changed from the start of a project to current times. My data is based off of trapping. **I was thinking of determining the peak annually, then doing an ANOVA or Linear Model. Is there a better way of doing this?**

****Changes in fork lengths****
I have fork length data for multiple rivers over a 15 year period. I wanted to analyze how hatchery or wild status predicts lengths. Are hatchery fish smaller/longer than wild? **I had thought to find the mean fork length for fish annually both by sex and hatchery/wild status, then do ANOVA or Linear Model. Is there a better way of analyzing?**

****Changes in Age Structure****
Through field sampling, I have scale analysis results telling me the age structure of each year's spawners. Similar to fork lengths, how has this changed over time, and specifically, as an effect of wild/hatchery status and sex.

Any help is much appreciated! Just looking for some ideas because while I really enjoyed ANOVA/regression analysis, I'm sure there are some much better ideas for these questions.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you interereted in Anova or regression ?

Comment: Either or, just trying to figure out which analysis would make the most sense in this case.

Comment: One-way Anova should be a good option for your issues - fork length and age-structure presuming that you are not interested in a single complete model.

Comment: Thank you. A 1-way ANOVA makes sense for those. I was also contemplating a 3-way ANOVA to look at what is a better predictor on fork length - sex, mark status, or age.

Comment: what is matk status ?

Comment: Three way Anova will be a complicated affair. WHAT IS your theme of study.

Comment: Mark status is whether a fish is from a hatchery, or is wild. So, 0 or 1.

Comment: I am not very clear about analysis relating to age-structure. what is your data and do you want to do a separate analysis and at what level.

Comment: I have a few thousand lines of data, with each giving me a fork length, sex, age, and mark status. I want to analyze the effect of mark status and sex as a predictor of age.                                                   
Secondly, I want to analyze the effects of mark status, sex, and age as predictors of fork length.                                                                    Last, I have data on the number of fish that have returned on specific dates over 15 years. I want to compare the mean return date over the years to see if they are stat. different and significant. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

In view of your comments(following your question), you can apply ANOVA to find out the effect of mark-up(hatchery Versus wild) and sex-type (male Vs. female) on fork-length. And two-way Anova could be implemented for evaluating the combined-effect of the specified variables i.e whether mark-up and sex-type together affect the fork-length significantly. Two way Anova will account for interactions. Given the nature of two variables - Age and fork-length, these may be analyzed by correlation-analysis and/or  regression analysis. The combined effect of all three variables may be estimated and tested with the help of lme - Linear mixed-effect model.

Comment: Great, thank you! Lastly, to compare the mean return peaks from each year, what would be best way to do so? I'd have 15 years.

Comment: mean return peaks - data ? annual ? for different categories or meta-analytic i.e. over

Comment: not clear. please explain - what is mean return peak?  For what do you want to estimate -  category-wise , sexwise ,  etc.

Comment: Please elaborate the mean return peaks and what is your data ?

Comment: I have dates with numbers of fish that returned each day for that year. I was going to convert this to Days after Trapping Began. So one year, my average peak might be 35 days, another year 30, and so forth. Thank you!

Comment: can't comprehend. Does that imply that  for 35 days there is  a peak on  on average. basis or something different ?

Comment: Sorry for confusion. To find the average return date annually, I had planned to calculate days after trap began. So in 2015 for example, the mean return date might be 35 days after trapping began, another year 30 days after.

Comment: did you have several trappings during each  year?  mean ?

Comment: Yes, so for each date, we have a number of fish caught that day. It's a 2 month span annually.